# How do I add a class to an ID when checking an attribute?

Tags: jquery

I am working on a solutions which is also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66824723/if-data-attribute-is-true-add-class).

Now I am close I think:

```
jQuery("#first-slide[data-isactiveslide="true"]").addClass("underline");
```

But I need to add the class to my ID (my button). How do I do this?
I thought like this, but it doesn't work:

```
jQuery("#first-slide[data-isactiveslide="true"]"){
   jQuery("#my-button").addClass("underline");
});
```

Any help appreciated
Best regards,
Skt

EDIT here is an image from chrome dev tools:
[image: data is visible true]

Comment: Try like this : `jQuery("#first-slide[data-isactiveslide='true']").length != 0 ? jQuery("#my-button").addClass("underline") : ""`

Comment: @Swati why use a conditional operator? it's literally the same number of characters as using an `if` here - it's not like you're even saving anything.

Comment: that looks much better than mine, but unfortunately, my site doesn't like it and I get a white page back. Could it be something with the code - could it be written differently? I usually end with "});" sorry I am a newbie...

Comment: @VLAZ I am not sure .. i saw this question and that came to my mind :P .

Comment: @Skt any error inside browser console ?

Comment: @Swati, I don't think so.

Comment: I added an image from chrome dev tools above

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the `jQuery` selector in a `if` to [check if it's found anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery), if so, add the class to the button.

```js
if (jQuery("#first-slide[data-isactiveslide='true']").length) {
  jQuery("#my-button").addClass("underline");
}
```

```css
.underline { text-decoration: underline; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='first-slide' data-isactiveslide='true'>#1</div>
<div id='second-slide' data-isactiveslide='false'>#2</div>

<button id='my-button'>Button</button>
```

**Edit**:
Same code, with `isactiveslide=false` showing button is not underlined

```js
if (jQuery("#first-slide[data-isactiveslide='true']").length) {
  jQuery("#my-button").addClass("underline");
}
```

```css
.underline { text-decoration: underline; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='first-slide' data-isactiveslide='false'>#1</div>

<button id='my-button'>Button</button>
```

Comment: yes, this almost works! The problem is, now when testing it, the data-isactiveslide="false" and despite this, the button is underlined. Very strange. As if it doesn't read the "true".

Comment: Mmm cant reproduce, If I change `data-isactiveslide='true'` to `data-isactiveslide='truteste'`, the button does not get the `underline` class.

Comment: I added an image from chrome dev tools above

Comment: The dev tools image does not provide enough info to get whats wrong. Could you maybe add a [mre] to the question?

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you, I must improve how I put questions.

Answer (score 0):

I had been struggling for a while, and during our discussion, I realised that I could look for another attribute other than the one mentioned above. I used the attribute of the active slide instead, with CSS, and it works!:

```
rs-module.the-whole-slide[data-slideactive="rs-1899"] .my-button{text-decoration:underline !important;}
```

Based on help from @Shakti

I mean, using true or false would have been much nicer. If anyone solved it, it would be great... But what works, works right.

Sorry, this answer differs from the question since I didn't provide the above info.

Best,
Skt